# How can i use gif image with QSplashScreen?

Tags: qt

I'm using QSplashScreen for displaying image during application start-up.

Now i need to use an animated gif image with splash screen. 
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The `QImageReader` reader class allows you to access the frames of an animation using the [`QImageReader::read`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qimagereader.html#read) function.

The documentation states:

> For image formats that support animation, calling read() repeatedly will return the next frame. When all frames have been read, a null image will be returned.

You will need to inherit from `QSplashScreen` and re-implement the `paintEvent` to draw the splashscreen. The `QImageReader::jumpToImage` function may be useful to select the correct frame from the animation.

You will need to have some system of triggering the splash screen updating, for example if you are loading lots of files in a loop, you could trigger a splashscreen redraw after loading every file.

Periodic calls to `QCoreApplication::processEvents` will allow paint events to process and `QWidget::repaint` will fire the repaint.

Pseudo code for this:

```
MySplashscreen screen;

// Loading loop
for (...)
{
    loadFile(...);

    screen.select_frame(...); // function to select correct frame
    screen.repaint();
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();
}
```